# glade: How to edit pages in a GtkAssistant

Tags: gtk, glade, gtk3

I would like to add content to the pages of an Assistant window (GtkAssistant) in Glade.

When I add a new assistant, no children appear under the GtkAssistant. Further I cannot select (or delete or change) the contents of the 3 default pages Glade produces -- I can only select the assistant itself.

So, I try increasing the number of pages to 5 and then adding a widget to one of the new pages. It gives me the error message: "Widgets of type Assistant need placeholders to add children."

Is this a bug, or am I missing something fundamental about how I'm supposed to configure an assistant window?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798890/how-do-i-edit-gtkassistant-on-glade) might be related; but it's very vague and has not been answered.

I am running Glade 3.12.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

[image: Error when I add a label to an Assistant.]

Comment: I don't think there's a "trick" that you're missing. More likely a bug. Try reporting it at bugzilla.gnome.org.

Comment: It seems this problem has already been reported: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=664276

Comment: The release notes for Glade 3.14.0 (http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/glade-devel/2012-September/001987.html) claim that this bug has been fixed. I will verify when I get a moment.

Comment: @IsaacSutherland has it been fixed yet?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha It looks like Ubuntu 12.04 still has release 3.12.1, and I don't have time at the moment to download and test a later non-precise-pangolin release. Maybe you can try 3.14 on Ubuntu 12.10 and let us know?

Comment: @IsaacSutherland my development machine is using 12.04 (due to longer lifecycle). Is it possible for me to update to 3.14 in Ubuntu 12.04? I am kinda new to Ubuntu and I cannot find any link on the net on how to update from 3.12 to 3.14 in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @HaikalNashuha I've never done it before but http://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning looks like a good place to start. Maybe `sudo apt-get install glade -t quantal` would work?

Comment: @IsaacSutherland I tried installing manual Glade from the website, apparently it is not compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 due to requirement gtk >= 3.6, while 12.04 using gtk 3.4.