# In Glade, how do I add a page to an assistant?

Tags: gtk, glade

After creating an Assistant window in Glade, I am presented with a window with three labels, each representing a page.

But how do I add another page and its corresponding widget?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Set the number of pages you need in the assistant's properties window. The number of pages should be greater than the number of child page widgets currently added to the assistant window.

   [image]
2. Re-order the existing child page widgets by changing their `Position` property under the Packing tab. You want to end up with the first position (position 0) empty. The easiest way to do this is to increase each child's position by one, starting with the last child.

   [image]
3. Now select the `assistant-action-area` object in the navigator. If no object occupies position 0, you should see a blank space in the Assistant's preview.

   [image]
4. Click on a widget from the side panel and add it to the blank area.
5. Repeat for every page you need to add.

Comment: When I do this I get the error message "Widgets of type Assistant need placeholders to add children.". All my widgets have a position higher than 1 and the number of pages is more than the amount of widgets. A similar issue has been reported for glade version 3.12 and supposedly fixed in 3.14 but I have this issue on version 3.38
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023809/glade-how-to-edit-pages-in-a-gtkassistant